# Doctrine 2 annotations, adding custom sql - spatial index

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to create spatial index in mysql via doctrine annotations on entity.

From what I see there has been pull request for defining index type (via flags option):
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/973
but in symfony 2.4 doctrine 2.2 is used which doesn't have this merged.

So, my question is, is there a way to specify some custom sql command to be run every time schema is updated/created ?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably can be done by doctrine migrations bundle http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The link in your question is now merged, so you can do:

`@ORM\Table(name="my_table",indexes={@ORM\Index(columns={"polygons"},flags={"spatial"})})`

Comment: There is a problem: Doctrine drops and recreates index defined this way.

`$ bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

The following SQL statements will be executed:

DROP INDEX IDX_8D93D64980D9E6AC ON my_table;
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX IDX_8D93D64980D9E6AC ON my_table (polygons);`